# Does Application Insights track referrer url?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I think I looked and searched everywhere but I could not find any charts or report with referrer traffic data. I am using the newest version that stores data in the preview Azure portal. In the old Application insights (that was in VS Online) had this data.

Does anyone know if and where it can be found in the new portal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/issues/727

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We don't have a native support for url referrer yet. As a workaround you could add a custom property to each JS SDK api call you need (like trackPageView). You'll have to set the property value yourself. I checked that this works:

```
    appInsights.trackPageView(null, null, {urlReferrer: document.referrer});
```

First two nulls make us to set page name and url automatically. 3rd parameter is a custom properties object. 
Then you'll be able to group by "urlReferrer" in the portal.

Comment: Can confirm that this is a great solution.

Comment: Is this still the proper method for handling this?  The methods in the `ai.1.0.4-build00190.js` looks a bit different and I'm not finding where to change the `trackPageView` method calls..

Comment: Note that the default tracking JS snippet already contains a `trackPageView` call, so adding this too would double the reported page views. So either delete the call from the tracking snippet or modify it to include `document.referer`.

Comment: @Matty good question, I asked it too: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/issues/727

Comment: @Max Shekhovtcov Why don't you have this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a property called "Page view referral url base" that you should be able to segment the chart or grid of page views.
In the Metric Explorer, Add a chart => Select Page View Metric => Turn Grouping On => select Page view referral URL base.

Comment: Thanks for that. Hoever it does not show any data even though site has been running for few weeks. It shows a lot of page views but not when you group by referrer url

Comment: @DmytroI. same for me

Comment: `Page view referral URL base` doesn't seem to exist anymore.